# Usage of -l for arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to use a arm-none-eabi-gcc to compile some mbed code offline and ran into trouble when I tried to move the mbed folder outside the directory. The command that comes out of the make file is

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -T../libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/MKL25Z4.ld -L./mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -o Example.elf main.o ../libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/retarget.o ../libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/board.o ../libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/cmsis_nvic.o ../libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/mbed_overrides.o ../libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/system_MKL25Z4.o ../libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/startup_MKL25Z4.o -lmbed  -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys -lmbed  -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys
```

The folder named mbed contains all the headers and .o files required for basic mbed programming. However, when I try to move the mbed folder to a different folder and address it relatively, I get an error saying:

```
cannot find -l../libraries/mbed
```

Is it wrong to give relative paths to the -l option? If yes, how do I work around this problem?

Comment: also note that if you just want to link a specific file that you know the path to, you just pass that filename to the linker without any prefix

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-L` option to gcc to indicate where libraries are to be looked for. See [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a file named `liblibrary.a`. The linker then uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.

The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with `-L`.

Comment: If I use `-L` it throws a completely new set of errors saying things like `undefined reference to wait_ms`. Why wouldn't it be possible to give relative paths to `-l`? I've been searching a bit online but haven't found the right differentiation between these two options.

Comment: And where is `wait_ms` defined? No, you shouldn't use path components with `-l`, the expected argument is just a library name and the linker does the searching in the places you've told it to search.

Comment: That makes sense. `wait_ms` is defined in a .o file that is included in the path. I read the documentation and added `-L../libraries/mbed` and then had `-lmbed` but this doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. The problem was that -L was not taking in relative paths. The new command looks something like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -T/<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/MKL25Z4.ld -o Example.elf main.o /<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/retarget.o /<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/board.o /<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/cmsis_nvic.o /<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/mbed_overrides.o /<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/system_MKL25Z4.o /<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries//mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/startup_MKL25Z4.o -L/<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries/mbed/TARGET_KL25Z/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -L/<path-to-folder>/workspace/mbed/libraries/mbed -lmbed  -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys
```

I'm not exactly sure why the relative path didn't work. One of my friends suggested that it may be because '..' is a symbolic link in some sense.